# Visual Studio Report Viewer does not connect to remote SSRS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

So i have setup SSRS 2014 on a test server and i have added 1 test report in the HOME folder. The report runs with out any problems. I can even connect to the report dashboard from my local machine by using the the IP Address xxx.xxx.xx.xx/Report_Server and run the report no issue.

The problem i am having is that in visual studio i have added the report viewer control onto an .aspx page but as soon as i make a call to the report server i get the following exception.

**Message = "The attempt to connect to the report server failed.  Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version."**

**InnerException = {"The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found."}**

the code i am using to connect to the server is as follows

```
rvReport.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/Report_Server");
rvReport.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials("Username", "Password", "Domain ???");
rvReport.ServerReport.ReportPath = "TestReport";
```

Something that i would like to mention is that for this test i am using the Servers administration account and password to connect to the reporting server and these credentials work if i navigate to the report dashboard URL from my local machine.

What exactly would the domain name be in the **ReportServerCredentials**? i have tried the IP address, the name of the server, the SQL instance name practically everything i can think of.

I have opened tcp ports 1433 and udp 1434 and allowed remote connections the db.

Is there another port that needs opening?

I have tried a ReportPath = "/TestReport".

I have also allowed http headers to localhost within the SSRS Config Manager.

I'm just at a loss right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, i found the problem. To connect to the report server dashboard via the internet you use the the IP xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/Report_Server which is the link found in the **SSRS Config manager > Report Manager URL** Page which is also the URL i was using in my code. i switched the URL in my code to match the URL found in the **SSRS Config Manager > Web Service URL** Tab and used my Servers Computer name as the DomainName and everything is loading correctly now in the Visual studio report viewer.

[SSRS Config Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIeVn.png)